# Angular4 Material MdTable not working in router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular-material

Could anyone help me to solve an issue when using an angular material table with Angular4 and Routing module.

I've created a punkler that illustrate my issue. The code was almoste copied form the original tutorial from material.angular.io.

As you can see, I expect to have a table displayed juste below the Hello Angular! v4.3.0 title.

Regards,

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/96ngX1EssWkukdUtSWx1

Comment: Why are you putting the plnkr in comment? edit the question

Comment: Because I'll have to add the punkler code inside my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this workaround to fix your issue waiting for bug to be fixed by angular material team: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5593.
Preferred workaround: force detectionChange in your component.

```
ngOnInit() {
  //data initialization
  this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
}
```